# rxjs subscribing late results to empty stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, event-loop

I have the following piece of code. As is, with a couple of lines commented out, it works as expected. I subscribe to a stream, do some processing and stream the data to the client. However, if I uncomment the comments, my stream is always empty, i.e. `count` in `getEntryQueryStream` is always 0. I suspect it has to do with the fact that I subscribe late to the stream and thus miss all the values.

```
// a wrapper of the mongodb driver => returns rxjs streams
import * as imongo from 'imongo';
import * as Rx from 'rx';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {elasticClient} from '../helpers/elasticClient';

const {ObjectId} = imongo;

function searchElastic({query, sort}, limit) {
    const body = {
        size: 1,
        query,
        _source: { excludes: ['logbookType', 'editable', 'availabilityTag'] },
        sort
    };
    // keep the search results "scrollable" for 30 secs
    const scroll = '30s';
    let count = 0;

    return Rx.Observable
        .fromPromise(elasticClient.search({ index: 'data', body, scroll }))
        .concatMap(({_scroll_id, hits: {hits}}) => {
            const subject = new Rx.Subject();

            // subject needs to be subscribed to before adding new values
            // and therefore completing the stream => execute in next tick
            setImmediate(() => {
                if(hits.length) {
                    // initial data
                    subject.onNext(hits[0]._source);
                    // code that breaks
                    //if(limit && ++count === limit) {
                        //subject.onCompleted();
                        //return;
                    //}

                    const handleDoc = (err, res) => {
                        if(err) {
                            subject.onError(err);
                            return;
                        }

                        const {_scroll_id, hits: {hits}} = res;

                        if(!hits.length) {
                            subject.onCompleted();
                        } else {
                            subject.onNext(hits[0]._source);
                            // code that breaks
                            //if(limit && ++count === limit) {
                                //subject.onCompleted();
                                //return;
                            //}

                            setImmediate(() =>
                                elasticClient.scroll({scroll, scrollId: _scroll_id},
                                    handleDoc));
                        }
                    };

                    setImmediate(() =>
                        elasticClient.scroll({scroll, scrollId: _scroll_id},
                            handleDoc));
                } else {
                    subject.onCompleted();
                }
            });

            return subject.asObservable();
        });
}

function getElasticQuery(searchString, filter) {
    const query = _.cloneDeep(filter);
    query.query.filtered.filter.bool.must.push({
        query: {
            query_string: {
                query: searchString
            }
        }
    });

    return _.extend({}, query);
}

function fetchAncestors(ancestorIds, ancestors, format) {
    return imongo.find('session', 'sparse_data', {
        query: { _id: { $in: ancestorIds.map(x => ObjectId(x)) } },
        fields: { name: 1, type: 1 }
    })
    .map(entry => {
        entry.id = entry._id.toString();
        delete entry._id;

        return entry;
    })
    // we don't care about the results
    // but have to wait for stream to finish
    .defaultIfEmpty()
    .last();
}

function getEntryQueryStream(entriesQuery, query, limit) {
    const {parentSearchFilter, filter, format} = query;

    return searchElastic(entriesQuery, limit)
        .concatMap(entry => {
            const ancestors = entry.ancestors || [];

            // if no parents => doesn't match
            if(!ancestors.length) {
                return Rx.Observable.empty();
            }

            const parentsQuery = getElasticQuery(parentSearchFilter, filter);
            parentsQuery.query.filtered.filter.bool.must.push({
                terms: {
                    id: ancestors
                }
            });

            // fetch parent entries
            return searchElastic(parentsQuery)
                .count()
                .concatMap(count => {
                    // no parents match query
                    if(!count) {
                        return Rx.Observable.empty();
                    }

                    // fetch all other ancestors that weren't part of the query results
                    // and are still a string (id)
                    const restAncestorsToFetch = ancestors.filter(x => _.isString(x));
                    return fetchAncestors(restAncestorsToFetch, ancestors, format)
                        .concatMap(() => Rx.Observable.just(entry));
                });
        });
}

function executeQuery(query, res) {
    try {
        const stream = getEntryQueryStream(query);
        // stream is passed on to another function here where we subscribe to it like:
        // stream
        //     .map(x => whatever(x))
        //     .subscribe(
        //         x => res.write(x),
        //         err => console.error(err),
        //         () => res.end());
    } catch(e) {
        logger.error(e);
        res.status(500).json(e);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why those few lines of code break everything or how I could fix it.

Comment: you are right, I think you need to subscribe before calling onNext

Comment: @FanCheung, any idea on how I can do this with what I've posted?

Comment: First of all you don't quite need a subject here, need to refactor searchElastic() 
and turn elasticClient.scroll into an observable. Then you can focus on chaining and combing observables .merge,combineLatest,forkJoin to make them all work together.

Comment: The reason your code  work before is you use setImmediate() to trick the execution order. Why it doesn't work now, i suspect is because the stream is completed. But fundamentally this is not the right design pattern for reactive functional programming.

Comment: @FanCheung, care to write an answer with a snippet of code of how I can achieve this without the subject? Thanks!

Comment: As a note, this code is a re-write of a previous version that was keeping all results in memory and thus I have to avoid keeping any large data sets in memory

Comment: it's quite hard to pick up from your code when it is quite messy. I don't understand why you have this infinite recursively call         
 setImmediate(() =>
                                elasticClient.scroll({scroll, scrollId: _scroll_id},handleDoc));
                        }

Comment: This is basically fetching 1 data point at a time from `elasticsearch` until there are no more data. I wanted to convert an `elasticsearch` query to an rxjs stream without keeping the results in memory and doing something like `Rx.Observable.from(results)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case is quite complex, you can start off with building up searchElastic method like the pattern bellow.

1. convert elasticClient.scroll to an observable first
2. setup the init data for elasticClient..search()
3. when search is resolved then you should get your scrollid
4. expand() operator let you recursively execute elasticClientScroll observable
5. use map to select data you want to return
6. takeWhile to decide when to complete this stream

The correct result will be once you do searchElastic().subscribe() the stream will emit continuously until there's no more data to fetch.

Hope this structure is correct and can get you started.

```
  function searchElastic({ query, sort }, limit) {
  const elasticClientScroll = Observable.fromCallback(elasticClient.scroll)
  let obj = {
    body: {
      size: 1,
      query,
      _source: { excludes: ['logbookType', 'editable', 'availabilityTag'] },
      sort
    },
    scroll: '30s'
  }

  return Observable.fromPromise(elasticClient.search({ index: 'data', obj.body, obj.scroll }))
    .expand(({ _scroll_id, hits: { hits } }) => {
      // guess there are more logic here ..... 
      // to update the scroll id or something
      return elasticClientScroll({ scroll: obj.scroll, scrollId: _scroll_id }).map(()=>
   //.. select the res you want to return  
    )
    }).takeWhile(res => res.hits.length)
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I first have to do a `elasticClient.search` for the first data and then do consecutive `elasticClient.scroll`s to get the next data. But each `scroll` requires a `scrollId` which is returned by either a `search` or a `scroll`, so each call depends upon the previous one

Comment: updated the answer, read about expand() operator in api doc and see if you be able to get there. expand(value=>innerObservable.map(res=>res)) beware about what to return in innerobservable inside expand, because it is recursive and will be return back to expand until takeWhile(res) stop the stream

Comment: The `rxjs` part works as expected! Thanks! (I'm having trouble with `elasticsearch` though, but I'll ask a new question)